# AngularJs. Unknown provider - routeParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I used many times code similar to this, but never have any error, but now, when I need to read url parameters, something went wrong.
Here is part of application configuration:

```
angular.module('NitkaApp', [
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'books',
    'details',
    'authors',
    'images',
    'dataService'
]).
    config([
        "$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", "$mdThemingProvider", function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $mdThemingProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true
            });
            $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
                .accentPalette('brown');
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: '/app/html/books.html',
                    controller: 'BooksCtrl'
                })
                .when('/book/:id', {
                    templateUrl: '/app/html/book-details.html',
                    controller: 'BookDetailsCtrl'
                })
```

This is part of controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('details', []).controller("BookDetailsCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$rootParams", "$mdMedia", "NitkaService", function ($scope, $location, $rootParams, $mdMedia, NitkaService) {
        //Getting external data from service
        NitkaService.getBook($rootParams.id).then(function(d) {
            $scope.bookDetails = d.data;
        });
```

And of course I have angular-route library link. Could you advise to solve this please? P.S. Of course I read all similar posts on SO.

Comment: `$rootParams`?  Do you mean `$routeParams`?

Comment: God damn, how can I do such mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `routeParams`  in your dependencies of the controller, Change

**From**

```
angular.module('details', []).controller("BookDetailsCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$rootParams", "$mdMedia", "NitkaService", function ($scope, $location, $rootParams, $mdMedia, NitkaService) {
        //Getting external data from service
        NitkaService.getBook($rootParams.id).then(function(d) {
            $scope.bookDetails = d.data;
        });
```

**To**

```
 angular.module('details', []).controller("BookDetailsCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$routeParams", "$mdMedia", "NitkaService", function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, $mdMedia, NitkaService) {
        //Getting external data from service
        NitkaService.getBook($routeParams.id).then(function(d) {
            $scope.bookDetails = d.data;
        });
```

Comment: Since this was such a simple typo, it'd have been better to close it as such...